# android, what is the overhead the LiveData would bring in

Tags: android, android-livedata

Question about using LiveData.

With LiveData you get for free that something like:

```
listener/subscriber support; 
lifeCycle awareness/management; 
cross thread marshaling, etc.
```

We could just use the liveData as the mechanism of delivering between any data repository to ui presentation for almost any case.

However in order to using it, it must bring in some objects that it needed, just like if you were to implement those features yourself there must be some supporting classes to be implemented.

Wondering how much/big the overhead it might be? Is it at a lever of could be simply ignored?

The case like do a search it could use LiveData, ui asking result from repository and observes a liveData, the repository posts the result and UI gets notified.

The same could be done without liveData as well (i.e. run coroutines suspended function to fetch from repository directly).

Would like to know whether the LiveData will bring some unnecessary objects, or the benefit over weigh them.

Saw [some post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502970/android-livedata-or-coroutines-channel) but did not find an official guid on when should use/ or not use LiveData, or LiveData is not suitable for such and such cases. Maybe it's just no overhead at all?

Any suggestion/thought?

Answer (score 0):

When working with MVVM (Model View ViewModel) you have two primary options to send data from the ViewModel to the View (updating the View).

- Data Binding
- LiveData

If you don't want to complicate the XML layout we usually use LiveData, which works based on **Observer Design Pattern**.
Using Kotlin Coroutines won't bring the full-featured package of LiveData.
With LiveData you have postValue from another thread to main thread,
You can observe changes from inside the view, and ...

PLUS: Kotlin Coroutines are for multithreading which is not relevant to LiveData, a component for holding data.

Comment: understand LiveData can bring a lot, my question if it is a straight forward single shot pull from host and then display, is it better to just go with bare bone approach i.e. making a directly call to repository and display the data. nothing else is needed. Pattern are there for solve specific problem, just dont want abuse any of them.